# ngTemplateOutlet not showing template passed as variable

Tags: angular

So I'm trying to build a dynamic table in Angular 8. My idea is to define the table as an array of columns, and define the content of those columns in `ng-template` elements so I can reuse some code.

I tried using `ViewChild` to store the ng-template elements inside the table definition:

```
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('column1') column1!: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild('column2') column2!: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild('column3') column3!: TemplateRef<any>;

  table = [
    {
      id: 'column1',
      title: 'Columna 1',
      template: this.column1,
    },
    {
      id: 'column2',
      title: 'Columna 2',
      template: this.column2,
    },
    {
      id: 'column3',
      title: 'Columna 3',
      template: this.column3,
    },
  ];

  tableData = [...]; // Rows of data
}
```

And then I tried to display the `ng-template` elements using `ngTemplateOutlet`:

```html
<table>
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let column of table">
        {{ column.title }}
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of tableData">
      <td *ngFor="let column of table">
        <ng-container
          [ngTemplateOutlet]="column.template"
          [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: item }"
        ></ng-container>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<!-- Columns content -->

<ng-template #column1 let-item>
  <div class="column">Columna 1</div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #column2 let-item>
  <div class="column">Columna 2</div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #column3 let-item>
  <div class="column">Columna 3</div>
</ng-template>
```

But I'm only getting a table with header and empty `td` elements. Here's an [example running on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xzq5i1?file=src/app/app.component.html).

What would be the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in description of usage `ViewChild` decorator.

It receives a reference from a template starting from a `AfterViewInit` hook and later, so you must pass data into your table there. You can do even more with a static content. It can be possible get references in a `OnInit` hook, just add static property to the decorator: `@ViewChild('column1', { static: true }) ...`

Comment: Thanks! Using `{ static: true }` and populating the `table` variable on `ngOnInit` hook worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar, but in a different way. I created this in Angular 15.2.3:

```
export class ColumnDefinition {
   caption!: string;
   binding!: string;
   type!: string;
}


@Component({
   templateUrl: './custom-datatable.component.html'
})
export class CustomDatetableComponent {
  @Input() columnDefinitions: ColumnDefinition[];
  @Input() datasource: any;
}
```

HTML -> custom-datatable.component.html

```
    <table>
      <thead>
      <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let column of columnDefinitions"><span>{{column.caption}}</span></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngIf="datasource && datasource.length > 0">
    <tr *ngFor="let item of datasource">
      <td *ngFor="let column of columnDefinitions">
      <div [ngSwitch]="column.type">
<ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'function'">
  <div [innerHTML]="item[column.binding]()">
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'string'">
{{item[column.binding]}}
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'date'">
{{item[column.binding] | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy'}}
</ng-container>
</div>
    
    </td>
    
    </tr>
    
    
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

For example when you want to use this component and need to fill it with data:

```
columnDefinitions: ColumnDefinition[] = [
  {caption: 'Title 1', binding: 'nameofpropertyfieldindatasource', type: 'string'},
  {caption: 'Title 2', binding: 'nameofpropertyfieldindatasource', type: 'function'},
]
```

The datasource can be a Array of any type. But keep in mind that the items in the array/datasource must contain property fields to bind to. See the binding field in ColumnDefinition.

This code is not tested and I'm having issues with styling. I think the most important thing takes place in the *ngFor of the tbody, if it comes to this question.